# shm_get_var vs apc_fetch

Tags: php

I just noticed you have in PHP the functions family: `shm_*`

Are there any reasons to use apc_fetch and not

```
shm_attach()
shm_get_var()
```

?

In which case you should use one or another?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APC has a lot of production use (facebook uses APC heavily, and has contributed many patches).

APC's offers several well-tested locking methods. [shm_* doesn't offer any built in locking](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.sem.php):

> Remember, that shared memory is NOT
>   safe against simultaneous access. Use
>   semaphores for synchronization.

shm_* fails to store data and throws an E_WARNING if you fill up your shared memory segment.  APC simply expires old keys if you run out of memory.

Long story short, you'd probably end up reinventing a lot of APC's features, and they'd inevitably perform worse, since APC's written in C.

Comment: really facebook uses APC and not memcached?? Do they have everything on 1 server?? :D:D

Comment: facebook has published some slide decks that explain that they use multiple levels of caching: execution-level caching in global vars, server-level caching in APC, and global caching in memcached.  Fetching stuff from APC is faster than memcache: the network is at least an order of magnitude slower.

Answer (score 0):

They provide simular functionality, but have a different purposes.

APC is a PHP-only feature. It doesn't require a context switch and is thus more efficient for sharing data within the PHP runtime in your Apache process.

SHM is a Unix system feature. It can be used to exchange data with native code or deamons on the server. It's basically just an in-memory tmp filesystem on Linux. (I've never actually used it.) But anyway, the main difference is that its purpose is interfacing to native apps.